# Laravel get Internal Server Error how can solve it?

Tags: laravel

Laravel get Internal Server Error how can solve it?

this is my web.php code

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/fleet', 'FleetController@index')->name('fleet');
Route::get('/offers', 'OffersController@index')->name('Offers');
```

When I link to fleet page, I will get Internal Server Error.

My folder is

```
resources
|-view
   |--index.blade.php
   |--fleet.blade.php
   |--offers.blade.php
```

This is index.blade.php code

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('fleet') }}">Fleet</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('offers') }}">Offers</a></li>
```

How can solve it?

My apache setting is

```
DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\wine\public"
```

my FleetController code

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
```

Fleet model

```
class Fleet extends Model
{
    //
}
```

still get error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.6 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: please try to run artisan command `php artisan serve` and go with served link instead of localhost and see if error disapears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look further about [laravel Route](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing)

**The most basic Laravel routes simply accept a `URI` and a `Closure`**

And now take a look on your code

```
Route::get('/fleet')->name('fleet');
Route::get('/offers')->name('offers');
```

You only give the `URI` but you dont give the closure

Basic route :

```
Route::get('/fleet',function(){
    // what do you want to do with that URI
})->name('fleet');
```

**You may also specify route names for controller actions:**

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserProfileController@show')->name('profile');
```

You need to create a file `UserProfileController` for the above route

Answer (score 0):

Those routes are not taking any action. You have to setup a controller.

Example:
`Route::get('/fleet', 'MyController@my_method)->name('fleet');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip introducing the controller you might go as simple as the current home `/` route.

```
Route::get('/fleet', function () {
    return view('fleet');
});
```